# Combine multiple column values into new column(s) if it's a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I'm even sure if this can be done or not, but I'm hopeful. Currently using mysql 5.7

I want to show all columns if they're duplicate entries based on the phone value. Then I want to select all the data from the higher id number into multiple new columns.

I have no idea how to create a view that will correctly show all duplicates, otherwise this would be easier to figure out. I used the following query to get the data.

Original table

```
id  customer_name   customer_email   customer_phone   comments
1   Jack            jack@jack.com    111-111-1111
2   Jill            jill@jill.com    111-111-1111
3   Tim             tim@tim.com      222-222-2222
4   Tonya           tonya@tonya.com  222-222-2222
```

Expected results

```
id  customer_name   customer_email   customer_phone   spouse_name   spouse_email    comments
1   Jack            jack@jack.com    111-111-1111     Jill          jill@jill.com   Jill jill@jill.com
3   Tim             tim@tim.com      222-222-2222     Tonya         tonya@tonya.com Tonya tonya@tonya.com
```

Ideally, all 3 columns would be populated, but spouse_name and spouse_email are more important since I can always combine them and insert into comments.

Comment: This seems stunningly presumptuous. What century are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry Do you have a better recommendation or just want to be rude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MysQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    max(case when rn = 1 then customer_name end) as customer_name_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then customer_email end) as customer_email_1,
    customer_phone,
    max(case when rn = 2 then customer_name end) as customer_name_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then customer_email end) as customer_email_2       
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_phone order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by customer_phone
```

When two rows have the same `customer_phone`, this puts the name and email of the row that has the smallest `id` in the first two columns, then those of the other row.

Notes:

- if there are more than two rows, rows after the second one are ignored
- if there is just one row, the last two columns are empty
- nothing in your data allows distinguishing the customer from the "spouse", so I used numeric prefixes for the column names instead

Comment: I should have said I'm using 5.7 Is there anyway to accomplish it using that version?

Comment: @J.R.: implementing such logic in MySQL < 8.0 will be challenging.

Comment: I just ran it locally and it works perfectly using 8.0 Is there anyway to combine customer_name_2 and customer_email_2 into a notes column or is that gonna require a separate query?